# Java-Abstract method not overridden

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

Can you help with one of the true/false questions asked in my test today:

If an `abstract` method is inherited by a subclass but is not overridden the whole subclass becomes `abstract`. Would this be `true` or `false`?

Comment: That is true, if a class has an abstract method either explicitly or inherited than it must be abstract.

Comment: That's a badly written question. If an abstract method is inherited by a subclass, but not overridden, then the subclass *must* be explicitly declared abstract. It does not magically "become abstract" -- it just won't compile until you declare it abstract.

Comment: @AndyThomas that is what I didn't understand when answering it. Would it be true or false if it wasn't declared abstract?

Comment: I agree with @AndyThomas it is a poorly written question. I am assuming the "correct" answer is false since the subclass must be explicitly declared abstract. True/False questions are often written to be mostly true with one small detail incorrect in an attempt to trick the test taker.

Comment: @JohnEakin - The test writer could make a case for either T or F, depending on whether they wrote the question poorly or intentionally wrote a trick question. As someone who wrote exams for a few years of undergrads, let me note that trick questions are unnecessary and unfair. The goal of the test should be to test your understanding. Clear questions are sufficient to establish the level of understanding.

Comment: @AndyThomas This begs the question, is the subclass abstract if it hasn't been declared yet but contains that abstract method?

Comment: It's kind of hard to say whether it's abstract if it's invalid.  It's like, if I declare something as `abstrac` is it abstract?  Perhaps the intent is there, but if the code doesn't compile, it's silly to think of it as abstract or not abstract.

Comment: @JohnEakin - The subclass will not compile if it has neither defined the abstract method or been itself explicitly declared abstract. A class that will not compile is neither abstract nor concrete -- it's not a class at all.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at:

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html](http://Java%20Doc)

It says:

> When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. However, if it does not, then the subclass must also be declared abstract.

Answer (score 0):

We are studying Abstract Classes in class this week as well, and as part of the weekly discussion post we have to respond to a question posed here on Stack Overflow, so this is my attempt.

Oracle States:

> When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. However, if it does not, then the subclass must also be declared abstract.

The answer to the true/false question would be true given that because the subclass method is not overridden, the subclass inherits an abstract method, and therefor is by default abstract given that only abstract classes can contain abstract methods.

> If a class includes abstract methods, then the class itself must be declared abstract.

Therefor it can be argued that the whole subclass "becomes" abstract as well.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but please see the comments above. After discussing this with the more experienced members on the site as well as with my JAVA teacher himself, the answer would not in fact be true. If an abstract method is inherited but not overridden AND the subclass is not declared abstract a runtime error will occur and the program won't compile successfully. Therefore, the class is not abstract because it doesn't compile.

Answer (score -1):

> If an abstract method is inherited by a subclass but is not overridden
>   the whole subclass becomes abstract.

**The answer is `false` because the class doesn't automatically or magically become `abstract`**, **rather you need to mark it as `abstract` if you are not overriding the one or more `abstract` methods.**

**The same concept applies even for `interface` as well** i.e., if you are not implementing (overriding) one or more `abstract` methods from the `interface` then you need to mark the class as `abstract`.

**So, correcting your sentence is that if an `abstract` method is inherited by a subclass but is not overridden, the whole subclass *needs to be marked as `abstract`* (this is `true`)**

Comment: I disagree, the expected answer is most likely false because the whole subclass must be marked abstract, it doesn't become abstract. It is a poorly written question attempting to trick the test taker.

Comment: @DanielBickler I agree that it's poorly written, but I think it's more likely to be unintentionally badly-written than an intentional trick.

Comment: @DM I hope you're right, but in high school and college I took a lot of tests with T/F questions that were unfortunately designed to be tricky and required considering every word when answering the question. In cases like these hopefully the instructor is willing to throw out the question if it was unintentionally tricky. Assuming their intent wasn't to be tricky.

Comment: Whatever the test writer's intent, the answer is "false". It is not an abstract class, it is, as @AndyThomas said, not even a class. It cannot be an abstract class if it is not a class, so it is false that it "becomes an abstract class". Whatever they intended, that is a fact, and facts, as they say, are facts.

Answer (score -1):

Just because it's true/false doesn't mean you can't attach an explanation.  Assuming your teacher knows what he is doing and is fair (which might not be a valid assumption) then a clear explanation of why you chose the answer you did would probably help.  If the test is online or scantron and you can't put an explanation right in the margins of the test itself, send him an email.

I would choose "true" with the explanation that it doesn't actually *make* the class abstract, but it does make it necessary that the class *be* abstract.  If the teacher is looking for "true" on a poorly written question, then you've answered "true".  If the teacher is looking for "false" on a trick question, then you've shown that you've seen the trick.  I think this maximizes the chance that you'll get credit.

Comment: Except that as worded, the correct answer is "false".

Comment: @LewBloch No, the correct answer is "N/A".  If the subclass is not abstract in those circumstances, there IS no subclass.  That's why an explanation with the answer is key.  I suggest "true" mostly because, IMO, the type of instructor who would blindly go with the answer and NOT look at the explanation is the type of instructor who would say the answer is "true".  The type of instructor who would say the answer is "false" already knows it's badly worded, and would probably accept an explanation showing the student knows what happens in that situation.

Comment: If there's no class, then it's false that it's an abstract class AND it's false that it's a non-abstract class. As every programmer knows, if `p AND q` is true, then each clause individually is true. Therefore it's false that it's an abstract class. Therefore the answer is "false". Q.E.D.

Comment: It's semantics.  If there is going to BE a class, someone had better add that `abstract` keyword if it's not there already.  The class becomes abstract because the programmer makes it abstract because they want their program to compile.

Comment: Anyway, you're answering the question as technically asked - I will admit to answering the related but distinct question of "how should I answer this to get credit."

Comment: In my experience, to get credit whether in school or at work, it is best not to deviate from the stated requirements. I've been shot down more than once for interpreting the problem statement with interpolations and assumptions. I recommend you-all avoid that danger and stick with the clear and unambiguous statement provided in this example. The question is, after all, clear and unambiguous, as is the logic for answering it. Luckily in the real world one usually has a chance to question and clarify the requirements.